# How do I break my comment section out of my page-content?

Tags: wordpress, comments

I have a WordPress site, and the comment section nested itself inside the content section. I'm trying to get it to drop under. I think it has to do with the way I've floated the content items.

Currently, in page sectioni section, I have something like this:

```
<div class="guts">
<div class="column-left">
<p>copy</p>
</div>
<div class="column-right">
[gallery]
</div>
</div>
```

with the css looking like this

```
.column-left{
float:left;
display: block;
width: 35%;
margin-right:5px;
}

.column-right{
float: right;
width: 65%;
margin-right:-5px;
}
.guts{
margin: -13px 15px;
display:block;
}
```

I tried to break it out using the php... but that isn't my forte and I was not successful, it seems like this could be done with proper css or php. I'd be open to either option.

Can see the site live [here](https://www.jpshots.com/wedding-photographer-in-overland-park-kansas-city/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using floats you need to ensure you use `clear:both` afterwards.

Try this

```
<div class="guts">
  <div class="column-left">
    <p>copy</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-right">
    [gallery]
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

See [here](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) for more information.

p.s. don't use inline styles like I have, use a class instead.